# Update Maven Dependencies eclipse

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I have change one of the file in my local maven dependency..now the project using that dependency is not updating according to change in dependency..i am new to maven so kindly help how to update that dependency in project using it.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>abc</groupId>
<artifactId>abcdef</artifactId>
<version>0.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

this is my current pom.xml

Comment: Is the dependency reachable for your Maven/Eclipse installation? Did you try an explicity "Maven -> Update Project"? Did you execute a "Run as -> Maven clean"?

Comment: i tried maven-> update project but no success..yes that dependency is reachable to me in eclipse..

Comment: Did u try maven clean install -U

Comment: try cmd mvn clean followed by mvn build

Comment: What do you mean by "the project using that dependency is not updating according to change in dependency"? Can you give example

Answer (score 0):

Your project using the dependency will not become notified about the change. To update the dependency information in all your projects, you can use [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)